# Ant failing when switching Java install: Syntax error: ")" unexpected

Tags: java, bash, ubuntu, ant

I am trying to switch from Java 6 to Java 8 on my server. I have endeavoured to do this by a) defining JAVA_HOME appropriately, and b) adding the the Java8/bin directory to the front of my PATH (so the correct java and javac are picked up).

However ant just fails with:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java: 1: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
```

I've taken this exact approach on my laptop and it works no problem (altho going the other way, switching from java 11 to 8). I've tried two versions of ant (an old c.2012 build and latest version 1.10.6) and get the same issue. Both versions of ant do not generate this problem if i just use java 6 (although I do get a subsequent java error, as expected, for 1.10 as this requires java 8 to run)

Any idea on what the problem could be? My server is running bash 4.2 / ubuntu 12.

Comment: Sounds like `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java` has been corrupted, because it's now running with `dash` and even if that was intended, there wouldn't be a syntax error on line 1. Can you open it in a text editor and see what it contains?

Comment: @thatotherguy - I think you are on to something! Doing "java -version" gives me: "-bash: /usr/.../java: cannot execute binary file." If I look inside with less, it's just a binary blob "^?ELF^B^A^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^C^@>^@^A^@^@^@<A0>..."

Comment: @thatotherguy - omg... have realised the problem. That java binary is x64, my machine is 32bit. I might just leave this up as a monument to my own stupidity

Comment: you're not alone :) thx for letting the post (arm 64 instead of x64 in my case :p)